# Importing a txt file when number of columns isn't known

Tags: r, csv, import, read.table

I need to read data from txt file into data frame. Number of columns aren't known, either datas are different. It may be any number. Here in example I showed 5 columns. But in real data it isn't known. It maybe 15 or 30 or more.

```
3401 6193 6237 
1556 2502 2883 4431 6119 
643 3723
```

I expect something like

```
  V1             V2             V3      V4           V5  
3401            6193           6237     NA            NA
1556            2502           2883    4431           6119 
643             3723            NA      NA             NA
```

I need data in data.frame or in matrix.

Comment: does the txt file have separate rows on separate lines always?

Comment: yes . Seperate line means next row. Space means the next column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count.fields` to find the length of each new table:

```
df.col.length = max(count.fields(test.txt,sep=" "))
```

Then you can use read.table with fill = TRUE to get your table into R:

```
test.df = read.table(test.txt, sep = " ", col.names = c(1:df.col.length), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: It will set column numbers to the number of elements in the first row. In this case column numbers will be 3.

Comment: As I wrote in the question number of columns aren't known it may be 30 or 40 or 80. The solution you offer is for fixed data.

Comment: And your code fails when there are 1001 columns.  or if there is 11 columns it creates 1000 column.

Comment: Yes, it turns out there is not a perfect solution for your example, but if your question doesn't (1) include example data that is representative and (2) you are required to do more work on your own (like removing extra columns or finding a different maximum value besides 1000), that doesn't make the solution wrong.

Comment: `count.fields` should solve your problem (see solution edits).